# Groovy replace one by one specific word from string with unique number

Tags: groovy

Replace the each word "nullnull" with unique number from given string

Each replace should be unique number. (timestamp if possible)

```
AMOUNTUSTOMNOTESRKNOTESY,AMOUNTURRNOTESNAMOUNTYAMOUNTOPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODNOTES,AMOUNT,PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHOD,NOTES,BankTransDate,BanktransRef,
3050346630503466,BanktransRefAMOUNTURRNOTESNAMOUNTYAMOUNTOPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODNOTESPBanktransRefAMOUNTURRNOTESNAMOUNTYAMOUNTOPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODNOTESP,-1.15-1.15,PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODirect PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODebitPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODirect PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODebit,nullnull,06/13/202006/13/2020,nullnull,
3098017730980177,BanktransRefAMOUNTURRNOTESNAMOUNTYAMOUNTOPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODNOTESPBanktransRefAMOUNTURRNOTESNAMOUNTYAMOUNTOPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODNOTESP,-1.15-1.15,PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODirect PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODebitPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODirect PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODebit,nullnull,06/13/202006/13/2020,nullnull,
3100110031001100,BanktransRefAMOUNTURRNOTESNAMOUNTYAMOUNTOPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODNOTESPBanktransRefAMOUNTURRNOTESNAMOUNTYAMOUNTOPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODNOTESP,-1.15-1.15,PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODirect PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODebitPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODirect PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODebit,nullnull,06/13/202006/13/2020,nullnull,
3143046931430469,BanktransRefAMOUNTURRNOTESNAMOUNTYAMOUNTOPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODNOTESPBanktransRefAMOUNTURRNOTESNAMOUNTYAMOUNTOPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODNOTESP,-1.15-1.15,PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODirect PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODebitPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODirect PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODebit,nullnull,06/13/202006/13/2020,nullnull,
3147508531475085,BanktransRefAMOUNTURRNOTESNAMOUNTYAMOUNTOPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODNOTESPBanktransRefAMOUNTURRNOTESNAMOUNTYAMOUNTOPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODNOTESP,-1.15-1.15,PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODirect PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODebitPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODirect PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODebit,nullnull,06/13/202006/13/2020,nullnull,
```

```
import java.io.File 

class Dcoder {  

    static void main(String[] args) {

        String result7 = "******"
        Date latestdate = new Date();   
        int i   
        for (i = 0; i < result7.length(); i++) {  
            // String time=latestdate.getTime();
            result7 = result7.replaceFirst("nullnull",latestdate.getTime());   
        }
        println result7
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally people show the code they tried solving the problem. Asking for the solution without trying is not the best way to go.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: Thanks for the quick update. Really appreciate your effort. Here, We have tried .splitEachLine(",")                                                                                        
                                                                                                                   

data.readLines().splitEachLine(",")  Getting error like >> the Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.splitEachLine() is applicable for argument types

Comment: @Marc i didn't get unique number while replace . Using splitline cmd

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of teaching, I have made the following example for you. First of all, because it's groovy, you don't have to have a class and a main method. Secondly, this is not the most optimal way of doing it, but it is a good illustration. Thirdly, you can experiment with the formatting of the timestamp to include only seconds or what you like. If you want every nullnull in the line to have a different tstamp, you'll have to experiment with looping through the values in the line by using for example `.splitEachLine(",")`

Also consider getting the data cleaned up at source if it is in your control.

Here's the example:

```
def data = '''AMOUNTUSTOMNOTESRKNOTESY,AMOUNTURRNOTESNAMOUNTYAMOUNTOPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODNOTES,AMOUNT,PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHOD,NOTES,BankTransDate,BanktransRef,
3050346630503466,BanktransRefAMOUNTURRNOTESNAMOUNTYAMOUNTOPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODNOTESPBanktransRefAMOUNTURRNOTESNAMOUNTYAMOUNTOPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODNOTESP,-1.15-1.15,PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODirect PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODebitPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODirect PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODebit,nullnull,06/13/202006/13/2020,nullnull,
3098017730980177,BanktransRefAMOUNTURRNOTESNAMOUNTYAMOUNTOPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODNOTESPBanktransRefAMOUNTURRNOTESNAMOUNTYAMOUNTOPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODNOTESP,-1.15-1.15,PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODirect PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODebitPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODirect PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODebit,nullnull,06/13/202006/13/2020,nullnull,
3100110031001100,BanktransRefAMOUNTURRNOTESNAMOUNTYAMOUNTOPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODNOTESPBanktransRefAMOUNTURRNOTESNAMOUNTYAMOUNTOPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODNOTESP,-1.15-1.15,PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODirect PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODebitPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODirect PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODebit,nullnull,06/13/202006/13/2020,nullnull,
3143046931430469,BanktransRefAMOUNTURRNOTESNAMOUNTYAMOUNTOPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODNOTESPBanktransRefAMOUNTURRNOTESNAMOUNTYAMOUNTOPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODNOTESP,-1.15-1.15,PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODirect PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODebitPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODirect PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODebit,nullnull,06/13/202006/13/2020,nullnull,
3147508531475085,BanktransRefAMOUNTURRNOTESNAMOUNTYAMOUNTOPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODNOTESPBanktransRefAMOUNTURRNOTESNAMOUNTYAMOUNTOPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODNOTESP,-1.15-1.15,PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODirect PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODebitPAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODirect PAYMNOTESNTMNOTESTHODebit,nullnull,06/13/202006/13/2020,nullnull,
'''

newData = ''

data.readLines().each { line ->
    def tstamp = new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss.SSSSS Z').toString()
    newData = newData + line.replaceAll("nullnull", tstamp) + "\n"
}

println newData
```